# Nuxt background-image vs Nuxt-Img

Tags: css, nuxt.js

In my solution I'm using [Nuxt-Img](https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img/) that returns resized images according to the current resolution.

But with the img-Tag it's quite hard/dirty to work with e.g. adding linear-gradient or focussing the image having overlays etc.

With a background-image it would be quite easier but it seems that nuxt-img doesn't support resizing for background-images.

### Update

Trying the following nuxt-image approach, the image size doesn't changes and is reloading the page always 418kb:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "SectionServices",
  props: {
    services: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    servicesVal() {
      return this.services.map((service) => {
        return {
          src: this.$img(service.src, {
            sizes: "xs:400px sm:640px md:768px lg:70vw xl:70vw xxl:70vw",
          }),
          alt: service.alt,
          name: service.name,
          link: service.link,
        };
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

So is there any great advise how to handle that?
What is your recommendation? Using nuxt-img or is it better to work with background-image?
Using Background-image, how can I handle the image-size that I don't need to load large images for e.g. mobile phones?

Comment: This one looks pretty much like your use case: https://image.nuxtjs.org/api/$img#usage

Comment: @kissu : Yes I tried this approach, but reloading the page in different resolutions the image is still 480kb, so unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: Even if you provide it an img srcset or maybe pass the width of the window?

Comment: Great hint. Adding the width directly the image gets shrinked. Now I need to find a clever way how to refresh the width by resizing the window.

Comment: You can add a specific listener for that.